# Подключить OpenCV

Tags: qt, qt5, macos, opencv

Не получается подключить OpenCV к Qt, ошибка выглядит следующим образом:

> opencv development package not found.

вот мой файл .pro:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста.

QT 5.12.1, OpenCV 4, Mac OS Mojave 10.14.4

Comment: А где сама либа? `LIBS += -L<path> -l<имя_либы_без_префикса_lib_и_расширения>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Либу надо  подключать следующим образом:

```
LIBS += -L<path> -l<имя_либы_без_префикса_lib_и_расширения>
```

В вашем случае:

```
LIBS += -L/user/local/Cellar/opencv/4.0.1/lib -lopencv
```

Кроме того, необходимо указать путь к заголовочному файлу:

```
// Используя ваш путь, но конечно, он может быть другой
INCLUDEPATH += /user/local/Cellar/opencv/4.0.1/include
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @alarih не пишите "спасибо" в комментариях. Для того, чтобы поблагодарить ответившего, вы можете проголосовать за ответ (стрелка вверх слева вверху) и пометить его верным (зеленая галка чуть ниже)