# Не могу подключить opencv_contrib к Qt 6.4

Tags: windows, qt, opencv

Линковщик не может найти определение для cv::Mat, постоянно получаю следующую ошибку:

```
undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()
error: debug/main.o:C:\pathto\main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat()'
```

Пробовал использовать стандартный помощник подключения библиотек в Qt Creator, однако после него возникают те же сообщения. У меня складывается ощущение, что надо подключить какой-то отдельный .lib файл под cv::Mat, однако в Visual Studio таких проблем у меня не было.

Вот мой .pro файл:

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++17 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += C:\\Users\\ass\\Documents\\ThirdParty\\opencv-4.7.0\\opencv\\build\\include \
LIBS += -L"C:\\Users\\ass\\Documents\\ThirdParty\\opencv-4.7.0\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc17\\lib" \
opencv_imgproc470d \
opencv_core470d \
opencv_highgui470d
```

И вот .cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
 
int main()
{
    cv::Mat frame;
    std::cout<< "Im working"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Что я делаю не так?
p.s. windows 11

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подключить OpenCV](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/964384/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-opencv)

Comment: нет. В том вопросе проблема заключалась в том, что автор не указал пути к заголовочным файлам и не перечислил сами имена .lib файлов, которые необходимо было подключить. В моём же случае всё это было выполнено, однако линковщик по-прежнему ругается на отсутствие ссылок (возможно проблема заключается в особенностях работы именно с opencv_contrib, а не стандратной opencv, но решения своего вопроса я так и не нашёл нигде.

Comment: У вас лишний слэш в конце строки  INCLUDEPATH

Comment: это так же не помогает (выдаёт ту же ошибку)
Я ещё пользовался стандартным визардом для подключения библиотек в Qt Creator, там немного синтаксис отличался, но даже таким способом ошибка не ушла

Comment: Компиляторы одинаковые используете?

Comment: Где? Ну в qt g++, а в visual studio - msvc

Comment: Для сборки либы и проекта компилятор должен быть одним и тем же (тип и разрядность)

Comment: А, понял. Компилятор который во время сборки opencv использовал не помню (или даже не знаю, конфигурировал и генерировал make файлы через cmake, а дальше пользовался ninja (но в нём вроде бы используется тот же g++)), попробую тогда пересобрать, убедившись, что использую один и тот же компилятор, спасибо!